# AWS VPN how to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

How can I connect to a AWS instance VPN from a ubuntu desktop?
I have configure a virtual private gateway, a customer gateway and the VPN connection.
The security group allows all traffic and the ACL to.

This is my VPN configuration.

```
! Amazon Web Services
! Virtual Private Cloud

! AWS utilizes unique identifiers to manipulate the configuration of 
! a VPN Connection. Each VPN Connection is assigned an identifier and is 
! associated with two other identifiers, namely the 
! Customer Gateway Identifier and Virtual Private Gateway Identifier.
!
! Your VPN Connection ID          : vpn-c9562082
! Your Virtual Private Gateway ID         : vgw-e0704394
! Your Customer Gateway ID        : cgw-d73201a3
!
!
! This configuration consists of two tunnels. Both tunnels must be 
! configured on your Customer Gateway.
!
! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! IPSec Tunnel #1
! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! #1: Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Configuration
!
! A policy is established for the supported ISAKMP encryption, 
! authentication, Diffie-Hellman, lifetime, and key parameters.
!
! Note that there are a global list of ISAKMP policies, each identified by 
! sequence number. This policy is defined as #200, which may conflict with
! an existing policy using the same number. If so, we recommend changing 
! the sequence number to avoid conflicts.
!
crypto isakmp policy 200
  encryption aes 128
  authentication pre-share
  group 2
  lifetime 28800
  hash sha
exit

! The ISAKMP keyring stores the Pre Shared Key used to authenticate the 
! tunnel endpoints.
!
crypto keyring keyring-vpn-c9562082-0
  local-address 193.145.247.253
  pre-shared-key address 52.30.80.142 key YsTEH4xu5t2Z7F.QtkvXy4NsSJ9fRJe2
exit

! An ISAKMP profile is used to associate the keyring with the particular 
! endpoint.
!
crypto isakmp profile isakmp-vpn-c9562082-0
  local-address 193.145.247.253
  match identity address 52.30.80.142
  keyring keyring-vpn-c9562082-0
exit

! #2: IPSec Configuration
! 
! The IPSec transform set defines the encryption, authentication, and IPSec
! mode parameters.
!
crypto ipsec transform-set ipsec-prop-vpn-c9562082-0 esp-aes 128 esp-sha-hmac 
  mode tunnel
exit

! The IPSec profile references the IPSec transform set and further defines
! the Diffie-Hellman group and security association lifetime.
!
crypto ipsec profile ipsec-vpn-c9562082-0
  set pfs group2
  set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
  set transform-set ipsec-prop-vpn-c9562082-0
exit

! Additional parameters of the IPSec configuration are set here. Note that 
! these parameters are global and therefore impact other IPSec 
! associations.
! This option instructs the router to clear the "Don't Fragment" 
! bit from packets that carry this bit and yet must be fragmented, enabling
! them to be fragmented.
!
crypto ipsec df-bit clear

! This option enables IPSec Dead Peer Detection, which causes periodic
! messages to be sent to ensure a Security Association remains operational.
!
crypto isakmp keepalive 10 10 on-demand

! This configures the gateway's window for accepting out of order
! IPSec packets. A larger window can be helpful if too many packets 
! are dropped due to reordering while in transit between gateways.
!
crypto ipsec security-association replay window-size 128

! This option instructs the router to fragment the unencrypted packets
! (prior to encryption).
!
crypto ipsec fragmentation before-encryption


! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! #3: Tunnel Interface Configuration
!  
! A tunnel interface is configured to be the logical interface associated  
! with the tunnel. All traffic routed to the tunnel interface will be 
! encrypted and transmitted to the VPC. Similarly, traffic from the VPC
! will be logically received on this interface.
!
! Association with the IPSec security association is done through the 
! "tunnel protection" command.
!
! The address of the interface is configured with the setup for your 
! Customer Gateway.  If the address changes, the Customer Gateway and VPN 
! Connection must be recreated with Amazon VPC.
!
interface Tunnel1
  ip address 169.254.20.134 255.255.255.252
  ip virtual-reassembly
  tunnel source 193.145.247.253
  tunnel destination 52.30.80.142 
  tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
  tunnel protection ipsec profile ipsec-vpn-c9562082-0
  ! This option causes the router to reduce the Maximum Segment Size of
  ! TCP packets to prevent packet fragmentation.
  ip tcp adjust-mss 1387 
  no shutdown
exit

! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

! #4: Border Gateway Protocol (BGP) Configuration
!                                                                                     
! BGP is used within the tunnel to exchange prefixes between the
! Virtual Private Gateway and your Customer Gateway. The Virtual Private Gateway    
! will announce the prefix corresponding to your VPC.
!            
! Your Customer Gateway may announce a default route (0.0.0.0/0), 
! which can be done with the 'network' and 'default-originate' statements.
!
! The BGP timers are adjusted to provide more rapid detection of outages.
!
! The local BGP Autonomous System Number (ASN) (65000) is configured
! as part of your Customer Gateway. If the ASN must be changed, the 
! Customer Gateway and VPN Connection will need to be recreated with AWS.
!
router bgp 65000
  neighbor 169.254.20.133 remote-as 9059
  neighbor 169.254.20.133 activate
  neighbor 169.254.20.133 timers 10 30 30
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    neighbor 169.254.20.133 remote-as 9059
    neighbor 169.254.20.133 timers 10 30 30
    neighbor 169.254.20.133 default-originate
    neighbor 169.254.20.133 activate
    neighbor 169.254.20.133 soft-reconfiguration inbound
! To advertise additional prefixes to Amazon VPC, copy the 'network' statement 
! and identify the prefix you wish to advertise. Make sure the prefix is present 
! in the routing table of the device with a valid next-hop.
    network 0.0.0.0
  exit
exit
!
! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! IPSec Tunnel #2
! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! #1: Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Configuration
!
! A policy is established for the supported ISAKMP encryption, 
! authentication, Diffie-Hellman, lifetime, and key parameters.
!
! Note that there are a global list of ISAKMP policies, each identified by 
! sequence number. This policy is defined as #201, which may conflict with
! an existing policy using the same number. If so, we recommend changing 
! the sequence number to avoid conflicts.
!
crypto isakmp policy 201
  encryption aes 128
  authentication pre-share
  group 2
  lifetime 28800
  hash sha
exit

! The ISAKMP keyring stores the Pre Shared Key used to authenticate the 
! tunnel endpoints.
!
crypto keyring keyring-vpn-c9562082-1
  local-address 193.145.247.253
  pre-shared-key address 52.30.118.25 key 5_KiSCRDEgIebtEdblX3Bu7k.QnPQYnf
exit

! An ISAKMP profile is used to associate the keyring with the particular 
! endpoint.
!
crypto isakmp profile isakmp-vpn-c9562082-1
  local-address 193.145.247.253
  match identity address 52.30.118.25
  keyring keyring-vpn-c9562082-1
exit

! #2: IPSec Configuration
! 
! The IPSec transform set defines the encryption, authentication, and IPSec
! mode parameters.
!
crypto ipsec transform-set ipsec-prop-vpn-c9562082-1 esp-aes 128 esp-sha-hmac 
  mode tunnel
exit

! The IPSec profile references the IPSec transform set and further defines
! the Diffie-Hellman group and security association lifetime.
!
crypto ipsec profile ipsec-vpn-c9562082-1
  set pfs group2
  set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
  set transform-set ipsec-prop-vpn-c9562082-1
exit

! Additional parameters of the IPSec configuration are set here. Note that 
! these parameters are global and therefore impact other IPSec 
! associations.
! This option instructs the router to clear the "Don't Fragment" 
! bit from packets that carry this bit and yet must be fragmented, enabling
! them to be fragmented.
!
crypto ipsec df-bit clear

! This option enables IPSec Dead Peer Detection, which causes periodic
! messages to be sent to ensure a Security Association remains operational.
!
crypto isakmp keepalive 10 10 on-demand

! This configures the gateway's window for accepting out of order
! IPSec packets. A larger window can be helpful if too many packets 
! are dropped due to reordering while in transit between gateways.
!
crypto ipsec security-association replay window-size 128

! This option instructs the router to fragment the unencrypted packets
! (prior to encryption).
!
crypto ipsec fragmentation before-encryption


! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! #3: Tunnel Interface Configuration
!  
! A tunnel interface is configured to be the logical interface associated  
! with the tunnel. All traffic routed to the tunnel interface will be 
! encrypted and transmitted to the VPC. Similarly, traffic from the VPC
! will be logically received on this interface.
!
! Association with the IPSec security association is done through the 
! "tunnel protection" command.
!
! The address of the interface is configured with the setup for your 
! Customer Gateway.  If the address changes, the Customer Gateway and VPN 
! Connection must be recreated with Amazon VPC.
!
interface Tunnel2
  ip address 169.254.20.226 255.255.255.252
  ip virtual-reassembly
  tunnel source 193.145.247.253
  tunnel destination 52.30.118.25 
  tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
  tunnel protection ipsec profile ipsec-vpn-c9562082-1
  ! This option causes the router to reduce the Maximum Segment Size of
  ! TCP packets to prevent packet fragmentation.
  ip tcp adjust-mss 1387 
  no shutdown
exit

! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

! #4: Border Gateway Protocol (BGP) Configuration
!                                                                                     
! BGP is used within the tunnel to exchange prefixes between the
! Virtual Private Gateway and your Customer Gateway. The Virtual Private Gateway    
! will announce the prefix corresponding to your VPC.
!            
! Your Customer Gateway may announce a default route (0.0.0.0/0), 
! which can be done with the 'network' and 'default-originate' statements.
!
! The BGP timers are adjusted to provide more rapid detection of outages.
!
! The local BGP Autonomous System Number (ASN) (65000) is configured
! as part of your Customer Gateway. If the ASN must be changed, the 
! Customer Gateway and VPN Connection will need to be recreated with AWS.
!
router bgp 65000
  neighbor 169.254.20.225 remote-as 9059
  neighbor 169.254.20.225 activate
  neighbor 169.254.20.225 timers 10 30 30
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    neighbor 169.254.20.225 remote-as 9059
    neighbor 169.254.20.225 timers 10 30 30
    neighbor 169.254.20.225 default-originate
    neighbor 169.254.20.225 activate
    neighbor 169.254.20.225 soft-reconfiguration inbound
! To advertise additional prefixes to Amazon VPC, copy the 'network' statement 
! and identify the prefix you wish to advertise. Make sure the prefix is present 
! in the routing table of the device with a valid next-hop.
    network 0.0.0.0
  exit
exit
!


! Additional Notes and Questions
!  - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud Getting Started Guide: 
!       http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide
!  - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud Network Administrator Guide: 
!       http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide
!  - XSL Version: 2009-07-15-1119716
```

Comment: "but if I try to ssh it, I can't" What happens when you try?

Comment: Can you provide a log of your attempt? Are you using the private IP address to connect? Correct keypair? Try the -v verbose option on `ssh` to diagnose.

Comment: I have configured VPN in AWS, so AWS give me a configuration file, and there appears 2 public IPs, in the VPN, so how can I configure in my ubuntu desktop to connect to thats VPN? AWS creates me 2 VPN tunnels as you can see in the configuration file.I think my problem is how to connect to that VPN, because I only have a config file .txt @JohnRotenstein

Comment: I think my problem is to connect to the VPN, because I only have a config file, so how can I connect in ubuntu desktop? @Kenster

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard VPN connection provided by an Amazon VPC is **not designed for occasional connection**. It is meant to be a permanent connection.

First, it's worth mentioning ways that a VPC can be connected to an existing ('on-premise') network:

- **Direct Connect:** A fibre connection between your existing data centre and AWS
- **VPN connection via a Virtual Private Gateway (VGW):** A permanent connection between an on-premise network router in your existing data center to an Amazon VPC (which connects to the VGW). This requires a permanently configured on-premise router and is not designed for temporary connections. Two IPSEC tunnels are provided for redundancy, each terminating on separate equipment within AWS.
- **Temporary (dial-in) VPN connection:** Used for occasional connection, similar to when you use a securID token to connect to your workplace network

It would appear that you are attempting to make temporary connections from your ubuntu desktop to the VGW. This is **not the intended use** of the VPN connection.

Instead, you should **use a software VPN solution** running on an instance within your VPC (eg [OpenSwan](https://www.openswan.org/), [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html)).

Some relevant articles:

- [Connecting Multiple VPCs with EC2 Instances (IPSec)](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5472675506466066)
- [Site-to-Site VPN between AWS VPC and Customer Site using Linux](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/site-to-site-vpn-between-aws-vpc-and-customer-site-using-linux/)
- [Setting Up IPSEC/OpenSwan in Amazon EC2](http://fortycloud.com/setting-up-ipsecopenswan-in-amazon-ec2/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Security group configuration and network ACLs allow inbound connections via port 22.

More information about here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html

Comment: I have configured ACL and security groups to permit all traffic inbound and outbound, but I can't ssh to the instance, but the pings works fine. @vladimir-mukhin

Comment: Did you add the internet gateway, to the route table in the subnet in which you instance is launched, since you are trying to connect to from internet. And also assign elastic ip to the instance since its a non-default vpc, all the nodes are assigned only the private ip.

Comment: Is the private subnet, and the internet gateway is by the NAT instance, so they connect to internet by NAT instance, the instances in the private subnet don't have public IP I have delete it, so I need a VPN to connect securely to the instances but I don't want that they have a public IP because then I could connect externally with the private instances. @mnkartik